# How to find through id in array of ids in db table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have an array of ids in a table column called event_ids

What i'm wanting is to do a search through the ids to find an idea, Something like

`Event.where(event_ids: [123456])` but it doesnt work on an array

any ideas how i can fix this to work?

```
2.3.3 :001 > array = [1317,4904]
 => [1317, 4904]
2.3.3 :002 > Event.where(ticketmaster: array)
  Event Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."ticketmaster" IN ('1317', '4904')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

However in one row in the ticketmaster column of the events table i have this:

```
---
- 1
- 1106
- 1317
- 4904
- 11648
- 13061
```

(formatted by psequel)

If I return it from the database it returns as an array

Answer (score 0):

"123456" is not an array. If you have something like

```
array_of_ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Then you can do something like:

```
Event.where(id: array_of_ids)
```

If `event_ids` is an array in some table and you have a record from that table in a variable, then you can do something like:

```
Event.where(id: variable.event_ids)
```

Not sure why you have an array of ids in a table, though.

Comment: I've got the ids in the table because i have multiple ids from one table needing to go into link to one row in the events table, The other table is called ticekt master. I treid what you gave and i got this in return (see edit)

Comment: An `Event` has_many `Ticketmasters` and a `Ticketmaster` belongs_to an `Event`, is that correct? And you want to find what, exactly?

Comment: Basically yes but i need the information from Ticketmaster row to use in the show method of event